# Why are my MRTK Buttons in Unity just Pink?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I added some MRTK Toolbox Buttons to a scene for an App I am trying to develop for Hololens 2, but those Buttons are always pink. They are clickable though.

[image]

These are the Plugins I installed:

[image]

Things I tried in order to get them to work (I always imported the Textmesh Pro files that are suggested):

- Switched around Building platforms
- Enabled all Windows Mixed Reality Platform Features
- Tried creating a fresh Project on Unity 2019.4.24f1 and Unity 2020.3.1f1
- deleted library folder

I think it may be a setting I have not set, but I am quite unexperienced. Is there any further troubleshooting I can do?

Addendum: I have an Error Message in the Console that I cannot get rid of. (It persists even in the newly created projects):

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Projekte\MyHololens\poc-3d-visualisierung-hololens\ButtonTest\Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.foundation@5db3df152788-1616077456490\SDK\Experimental\InteractiveElement\Examples\Scripts\CustomStateExample\KeyboardState'.
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (System.Int32 errorCode, System.String maybeFullPath) [0x000f7] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].HandleError (System.Int32 hr, System.String path) [0x00006] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].CommonInit () [0x00054] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1[TSource]..ctor (System.String path, System.String originalUserPath, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.IO.SearchResultHandler`1[TSource] resultHandler, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x000d6] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.CreateFileNameIterator (System.String path, System.String originalUserPath, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean includeFiles, System.Boolean includeDirs, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00009] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames (System.String path, System.String userPathOriginal, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean includeFiles, System.Boolean includeDirs, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x0001c] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles (System.String searchPattern) [0x0000e] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x00002] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs(System.Collections.ArrayList,string)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFilesSubdirs (System.Collections.ArrayList l, System.String pattern) [0x0002f] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles (System.String searchPattern, System.IO.SearchOption searchOption) [0x00017] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(string,System.IO.SearchOption)
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Editor.OnLoadUtilities.FindShaderFolderInPackage () [0x0005f] in C:\Projekte\MyHololens\poc-3d-visualisierung-hololens\ButtonTest\Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.standardassets@de5423dc1456-1616077455335\EditorUtilities\OnLoadUtilities.cs:152 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Editor.OnLoadUtilities.EnsureShaders (System.Boolean bypassIgnore) [0x00001] in C:\Projekte\MyHololens\poc-3d-visualisierung-hololens\ButtonTest\Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.standardassets@de5423dc1456-1616077455335\EditorUtilities\OnLoadUtilities.cs:42 
  at Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.Editor.OnLoadUtilities..cctor () [0x00001] in C:\Projekte\MyHololens\poc-3d-visualisierung-hololens\ButtonTest\Library\PackageCache\com.microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.standardassets@de5423dc1456-1616077455335\EditorUtilities\OnLoadUtilities.cs:23 
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (System.Type[])
```

Comment: Looks like the "shader" on your material is wrong. Since I have not used MRTK myself I can't say much more, but this looks like a solution: [Migrating to MRTK2: Mixed Reality Toolkit Standard Shader 'Breaks'](https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-to-mrtk2-mixed-reality-toolkit-standard)

Comment: The Fields are greyed out but I noticed an Error Message that seems to reoccur in every Project, even if its fresh. I added it to the question

Comment: Pink always is an error in the shader ... To the error: try to delete the library and let unity rebuild it with the next start .. usually this only happens when upgrading existing projects to a newer Unity version .. also make sure that the MRTK version you are using supports the Unity version you are using

Comment: clearing the library does not work unfortunately. The error stays the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The Problem was that the MRTK Feature Tool Installer Beta Version installed the Packages without assets as the Unitypackages from the Github Repository do.
This caused the Error. Just install the Unity packages directly from the Github Repository and it will work.

To elaborate further on this:
The packages wont get imported by the mrtk feature tool if the max. string length of 255 gets exceeded for a subfolder. This is a pretty annoying thing as you have to keep your projects basically in the root of your drive.